# Expected==Got doctests failing

Tags: python, doctest

Learning how to use doctest today.  Earlier I found out about having to add <BLANKLINE>.  Now how do I get the remaining failing tests to pass?  For all three there's no difference between Expected and Got:

```
C:\Windows\System32>python C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3
5-32\Lib\exemplarypy.py
**********************************************************************
File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\exemplarypy.
py", line 27, in __main__.find_name
Failed example:
    print(exemplarypy.find_name(""))
Expected:
    First cell must contain '.' xor '('
    None
Got:
    First cell must contain '.' xor '('
    None
**********************************************************************
File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\exemplarypy.
py", line 38, in __main__.find_name
Failed example:
    print(exemplarypy.find_name("(."))
Expected:
    First cell cannot contain both '.' and '('
    None
Got:
    First cell cannot contain both '.' and '('
    None
**********************************************************************
File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\exemplarypy.
py", line 41, in __main__.find_name
Failed example:
    print(exemplarypy.find_name("x(."))
Expected:
    First cell cannot contain both '.' and '('
    None
Got:
    First cell cannot contain both '.' and '('
    None
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   3 of  11 in __main__.find_name
***Test Failed*** 3 failures.

C:\Windows\System32>
```

The file being run:

```
import sys

class HaltException(Exception): pass

def find_name(cell_value):
    """
    Return the (denuded) token that comes after "[example " in cell_value.

    cell_value's parenthetical argument or ".py" will be excluded:
        [example FizzBuzz(x, y, z)] => FizzBuzz
        [example FizzBuzz.py]       => FizzBuzz

    Doctesting:
>>> import exemplarypy
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("t(("))
t
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("(("))
<BLANKLINE>
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("("))
<BLANKLINE>
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name(""))
First cell must contain '.' xor '('
None
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("x(adsf)"))
x
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("asdf.txt"))
asdf
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name(".asdf.txt"))
<BLANKLINE>
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("x.asdf.txt"))
x
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("(."))
First cell cannot contain both '.' and '('
None
>>> print(exemplarypy.find_name("x(."))
First cell cannot contain both '.' and '('
None

    """
    try:
        if cell_value.find(".") > -1:
            if cell_value.find("(") > -1:
                raise HaltException("First cell cannot contain both '.' and '(' ")
            boundary = cell_value.find(".")
            return cell_value[0:boundary]
        if cell_value.find("(") > -1:
            boundary = cell_value.find("(")
            return cell_value[0:boundary]
        raise HaltException("First cell must contain '.' xor '(' ")
    except HaltException as h:
        print(h)

# To test the embedded docstring documentation:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Addendum: Compared Expected and Got text with Show All Characters in Notepad++; their whitespace are identical.

Comment: Is it related to the white space at the end of your error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctest failing inspite of having correct output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650184/doctest-failing-inspite-of-having-correct-output)

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's true that the two questions have whitespace solutions, but this is not a duplicate because here, the space that needed to be removed was in the program proper, not in the doctests.

Answer (score 0):

Good call, @jonrsharpe, thanks: I simply had to remove the space at the end of these strings, i.e., between the last single-quote and double-quote.

```
raise HaltException("First cell cannot contain both '.' and '(' ")
```

and

```
raise HaltException("First cell must contain '.' xor '(' ")
```

Now all tests pass.